# Multiple timers in windows service not working properly

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

I have 2 different timers in my windows service each of which I am running at intervals of every 5 seconds, however they are both not being run at the same time.

My logs simplified logs look like the following

```
11:49:00 : Timer1
11:49:05 : Timer1
11:49:10 : Timer1
11:49:15 : Timer1
11:49:20 : Timer1
11:49:25 : Timer1
11:49:30 : Timer1
11:49:35 : Timer1
11:49:48 : Timer2
11:49:53 : Timer2
11:49:58 : Timer2
```

This continues with just one being activated for the correct period of 5 seconds then the other. I want both of them to be run.

I understand you will ask "why not put them in the same timer?" but i will be adding multiple more timers and the timing of these events are likely to change so I'd really like to fix this problem just now.

Here is my code,

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //Read or Create xml file to get necessary settings
        SerializeIformBuilder();

        //Checks for any user changes that may have occurred
        var manageUsers = new App.BLL.ManageUsers();

        System.Timers.Timer CreateNewUserTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        System.Timers.Timer PasswordUpdateTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        //Create Timer interval events
        CreateNewUserTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(manageUsers.TimedEvent_CreateNewUsers);
        CreateNewUserTimer.Interval = 5000; //Once every 5 seconds
        CreateNewUserTimer.Enabled = true;

        PasswordUpdateTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(manageUsers.TimedEvent_PasswordUpdate);
        PasswordUpdateTimer.Interval = 5000; //Once every 5 seconds
        PasswordUpdateTimer.Enabled = true;

    }
```

Comment: System.Timers.Timer is a very nasty timer.  90% of all "it doesn't work" problems with it are caused by not using try/catch in the Elapsed event handler and logging the exception.  And 5% are caused by using AutoReset = true like you do.  Final 5% are caused by not properly making code threadsafe.  You **must** log exceptions, rock-hard requirement.

Comment: I have added in a bunch of logging information, you are right, it is needed. I managed to fix a small problem with my code, but the problem is now that if one event handler is executing when another timer is activated then whatever method is currently being executed will just be stopped mid flow. I think I need some sort of threading to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

The `Interval` of `Timer` is not actually guaranteed, same as you can't count on `Thread.Sleep(5000)` sleeping *exactly* 5 seconds.

If both delegates need to be executed at the exact same time, you'll need to implement your own special timer, e.g. one that holds multple delegates and knows their execution intervals.

simplified:

```
public class Job
{
     public int ExecutionInterval { get; set; }
     public Action Action { get; set; }
}

public class TimedExecutionHandler
{
    private List<Job> jobs = new List<Job>();

    public void Start()
    {
        // start internal thread on loop
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
         // interrupt thread
    }

    public void RegisterJob(Job job)
    {
        // store job
    }

    private void Loop()
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            count++;
            foreach (Job job in this.jobs)
            {
                if (count % job.ExecutionInterval == 0)
                {
                    job.Action();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also had this issue, if your timers are running multiple things or doing complex calculations sometimes your program can run out of space, designated ram or overall just get too big(in terms of size and running lines of code). Just keep this in mind next time your using multiple timers or performing complicated tasks- your application had a designated amount of memory and timers use the memory up like crazy. Thanks! I hope that helped!

Comment: This post gives a guideline but does not provide a concrete solution or answer; be more specific.